# Trimming bad data around border of NAIP imagery using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, clip, naip

I am working with NAIP imagery from various years. Several of the images have bad data around the borders, see image. This is what it looks like without the no data values being shown. I need to trim this off because it is causing problems when I mosaic one NAIP image with another. My idea is to digitize a polygon around the raster, just inside the boundary of the bad pixels, then clip to that. This problem is occurring on multiple images though and I'm hoping to find a faster way of doing this.

Any other ideas on how to trim off say the 20 outer most pixels all the way around a raster image file?

I have been working in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]